# ERC-1155 interface with MetaMask mobile

Tags: metamask, nft

I am currently developing a contract that issues a single NFT per usage, I have implemented the token part with the ERC-1155 standard imported from [open-zeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol).
When adding my NFT to Metamask mobile it shows under "Untitled Collection" as a gray image with the id number and nothing else.
I was trying to find out how Metamask decides what to name the collection or which image to display. I'm guessing this has something to do with metadata but I'm not sure in what way.

My NFT does not correspond with any media or file, but I can try to create an image to have a Metamask display for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer - it seems that the NFT thumbnail image is taken by Metamask mobile from the metadata of the ERC1155 token contract.
Solidity:

```
constructor() ERC1155("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/metadata-json-on-ipfs")
```

JSON metadata:

```
{
  "name" : "<name>",
  "description" : "<description>",
  "image" : "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/thumbnail-taken-from-here",
  "attributes" : []
}
```

I have yet to discover the answer to the part about changing the collection's name - it was elevated to a support issue by Metamask's support team but I have not yet received a reply.

Comment: Any update on this? Same for the "Untitled Collection", image and all other attributes are ok....

Comment: Sorry Metamasks support was unhelpful, I'm still not sure what field would affect the collection name..